# Flask and rq-scheduler: Working outside of application context

Tags: flask, redis, rq

I want to start a background job that does a periodic sync when I start the flask application.
This works well, but in the task function I want to access a logger that was defined outside. While this also works in the responsible class, the application context does not seem to be available in the task itself.

**init**.py (folder app)

```
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue
from rq_scheduler import Scheduler
from datetime import datetime
import logging
from app.data.sync import Sync


def create_app():

    app = Flask(__name__)

    logging.basicConfig(filename="tasks.log", level=logging.INFO, format=f'%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(threadName)s : %(message)s')
    app.logger.info("Start Service")

    # Within the blueprints app can be accessed.
    #
    # from app.auth import bp as auth_bp
    # app.register_blueprint(auth_bp, url_prefix='/auth')

    with app.app_context():
        redis = Redis()
        queue = Queue('tasks', connection=redis)
        scheduler = Scheduler(queue=queue, connection=redis)

        sync = Sync()
        sync.logging_test()

        scheduler.schedule(scheduled_time=datetime.utcnow(),
                           func=sync.data_sync,
                           interval=10,
                           repeat=3
                           )

    return app
```

sync.py (folder app)

```
from flask import current_app
from time import sleep


class Sync():

    def logging_test(self):
        current_app.logger.info("this is running fine")

    def data_sync(self):
        #current_app.app_context().push()

        current_app.logger.info("Start sync")
        print("task")
        sleep(2)
        print("another task")
        current_app.logger.info("End sync")
```

app.py (outside)

```
from app import create_app


create_app()
```

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 1068, in perform_job
    rv = job.perform()
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 847, in perform
    self._result = self._execute()
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 870, in _execute
    result = self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/user/project/./app/data/sync.py", line 14, in data_sync
    current_app.logger.info("Start sync")
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 316, in __get__
    obj = instance._get_current_object()  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 513, in _get_current_object
    raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that in rq functions, there really doesn't seem to be any other way to get the Flask Context other than to recreate the app.

```
    app = create_app()
    app.app_context().push()
```

This creates a new app, but it has access to the config.

The only downside is that you have to be careful to really only create general things in create_app(). If you start a job here, it will be started every time the function is called. Since this also happens if you use several workers, for example with gunicorn, a job handling must be implemented here.